# vb.net call to google api using Eircode to get full address

Tags: vb.net, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get the full address from an Irish Eircode, using the Google Geocoding API and VB.NET. I am getting the results back but the address is missing street level, not sure why?

Here is my code... I think Google can't provide the full address, is there any other way?

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim address = "" 

    Try

        '*****  Check Eircode First ******
        If Me.tbEircode.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Eircode, please correct")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        MessageBox.Show(Me.tbEircode.Text & " Eircode sent to Google Maps")
        '***************  Get them in order with | and destination address
        Dim OrgAddress As String = ""
        OrgAddress = Me.tbEircode.Text 
        address = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:F*****|country:IE&key=***************"
        MsgBox(address)
        Using client As New Net.Http.HttpClient(), result = Await client.GetAsync(address)
            If result.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim content = Await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
                Dim response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Response)(content)
                Me.tbAddress1.Text = response.status
                Me.tbAddress2.Text = response.formatted_address.ToString  
            Else
                Me.tbAddress1.Text = "error downloading"
            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Google Distance Calculator")

    End Try
```